# Location not accurate and geting an exception in the DDMS

Tags: android, mapping, location, emulation

I am using osmdroid to display a map from MAPNIK and set the center of the map at aspecific location
the applcation works with no errors, but the map is center at a location that is far from the point that I especified in the code, I set the location(lat and long) from the code I needed that way I don't want to send them from the DDMS, My code is:

```
Double latitude = 15.610793;
Double longitude =  32.540152;
int lat = (int) (latitude * 1E6); 
int lng = (int) (longitude * 1E6); 
GeoPoint myPoint = new GeoPoint(lat, lng); 
// show first message
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
    "latitude is :"+lat+"lng is: "+lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();


    mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK); 
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setCenter(myPoint);
    mapController.setZoom(15);
```

and I also have this error in the emulator:

```
[2012-06-16 00:05:21 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:573)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:672)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2012-06-16 00:05:21 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:573)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:672)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

sory I ment error not exception and as I said it is in the console labled: DDMS, so the app works fine and does not crash

Comment: I also notice that when I test it in emulator with google API the location is acurate, I don't know why?

Comment: You  have to use the  Google APIs  to use the MapView I think.

Comment: I siad I am using osmdroid api and that means, I don't need GAPI

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue.  Try reversing the order of the following statements:

```
mapController.setCenter(myPoint);
mapController.setZoom(15);
```

Hope that helps!